# JS file not working inside innerhtml

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a div with dynamically content.

```
<div id='data'></div>
```

inside div is a table with class.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-expandable table-striped">
```

'table-expandable' execute with this js file

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets_d/expand/bootstrap-table-expandable.js"></script>
```

when page refresh this work fine,
but when I load dynamically div with ajax

```
 $(document.getElementById(data)).html(dynamiclyTable);
```

script on js file does not work, this is script on js file

```
(function ($) {
$(function () {
    var i=0;
    $('.table-expandable').each(function () {
        var table = $(this);
        i++;
        alert(i);
        table.children('thead').children('tr').append('<th></th>');
        table.children('tbody').children('tr').filter(':even').each(function () {
            var element = $(this);
            element.append('<td><div class="table-expandable-arrow"></div></td>');
        });
        table.children('tbody').children('tr').filter(':odd').hide();
        table.children('tbody').children('tr').filter(':even').on('click',function () {
               var element = $(this);
                element.next('tr').toggle('slow');
                element.find(".table-expandable-arrow").toggleClass("up");
        });

    }); 
});
})(jQuery);
```

Is there a way to call js file after div load dynamically content ?
Thanks

Comment: was the js before, or after the table?

Comment: i put js  after and before the table , but no difference

Comment: Why doesn't it work? is it not running? is it not finding the table? is jquery not defined at that point for some weird reason?

Comment: js file its not running, but when i refresh page, js file is running

Comment: .html behind the scenes uses .innerHTML, which doesn't execute script tags. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Thank Kevin B for your advice . I still try another way to fix it this case